# Parsing XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm using this PHP to parse a XML file:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.imgur.com/2/image/zzFV5.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child) {
    echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
}
?>
```

How can I display the parsed content from the XML in my HTML file?
Something like:

```
Image Views:<br/>
<?php echo ( $_REQUEST['views']) . ;?>
```

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: There's not really enough information here to help you.  If you want to just display everything from the XML you can just change your echo statements to variable assignments.  ex: `$html .= $xml->getName() . "<br />";`, but if you're looking to display a specific part of your XML, you'll need to be more explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.imgur.com/2/image/zzFV5.xml");
echo "Views: " . $xml->image->views;
```

That code outputs the views of that image from the XML file. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes that's it! :) Sorry I'm new to PHP and XML. What it's the cleanest way to write this? What can I optimize?: `<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.imgur.com/2/image/zzFV5.xml");
echo  $xml->image->views;  
echo $xml->image->datetime;  
echo $xml->image->type;  
?>


<u>Views:</u><br/>
<?php ( $_REQUEST['views']) ;?>
<br/>
<u>Date:</u><br/>
<?php ( $_REQUEST['datetime']) ;?>
<br/>
<u>Type:</u><br/>
<?php ( $_REQUEST['type']) ;?>`

Comment: @Michael I don't know what you're trying to do with the $REQUEST variable, I presume you meant $_REQUEST and if so, it's got nothing to do what you're trying to do. I'm guessing this is the code you want:

`<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://api.imgur.com/2/image/zzFV5.xml");
?>
<u>Views:</u><br/>
<?php echo $xml->image->views; ?>
 <br/>
<u>Date:</u><br/>
<?php echo $xml->image->datetime; ?>
<br/>
<u>Type:</u><br/>
<?php echo $xml->image->type; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

> You should state problem with more
>   details.  You can use asXML(),
>   SimpleXMLElement::asXML  Which will
>   return a well-formed XML string based
>   on SimpleXML element.
>
> examplenode : The node which contains
>   image

```
$xml_str = file_get_contents("file.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_str);
$result = $xml->xpath('//examplenode');
echo $result[0]->asXML();
```

Comment: @georgiecasey Awesome! Now I understand how it works. Thanks for lighting me up!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
   <?php
    $html="";
    $url="http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/586733.rss";
    $xml=simplexml_load_file($url);
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
        $title=$xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
        $html.="<div><center>$i.$title</center></div><hr/>";
    }
    echo $html ;
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```